# Sitecore Publishing Service Dashboard is empty

Tags: publishing-service

We have **Sitecore 9.3** instance with installed **Sitecore Publishing Service 4.1.0** and **Sitecore Publishing Service Module 9.3.0**.

Publish itself works fine for all targets: items have appeared in corresponding databases. But when we navigate to `Publishing Dashboard` - it is empty *(no active/queued/compeleted jobs)*.

There is an error in the browser console:

```
Requested URL: "https://mywebsite.com/sitecore/api/ssc/publishing/jobs/%7B00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000%7D/All?sourceDatabase=master"
Status: 500
Message: "Nullable object must have a value."
```

[image]
We have a lot of environments for our solution and faced this issue many times. Almost always it was resolved by `sitecore_master_index` rebuilding. Now we have **two CM servers** with **load balancer**, each CM server has **its own Publishing Service** hosted at the same server.

What we try to do:

1. Rebuild `sitecore_master_index`
2. Clear browser cache and restart App pool/IIS
3. Clear `Temporary Asp.Net files` from IIS

It did not help, the issue is still present. Did you face this issue or have any ideas on how to fix it?

Comment: If there are 2 CM, is there an instance that is running as an indexing role ?

Comment: No, we do not have separate instance for indexing. Both CM servers have single one common master database and index in Solr.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We found a solution that worked - clear `dbo.Publishing_JobQueue` table in `master` database:

```
 delete from [mywebsite_Master].[dbo].[Publishing_JobQueue]
```

It is very strange, besause of all records in this database look fine:

[image]

After deleting this data, `Publishing Dashboard` starts to work as expected: tables on the page are populated with new publishing jobs statistics.

*This solution works, but keep in mind that by clearing this table you lose statistics about past publishing jobs.*

Comment: The publishing service is meant to have a scheduled periodic task to clean up some of those records.

Answer (score 3):

This is a confirmed issue in Publishing Module 9.3.
Ticket number 381220.

Fixed in 10.0

> ​​The OperationCompleteTimestamp is set to null during a publishing job and this causes a nullable exception on the Sitecore side and empty data in the dashboard​.